# Can going to implementation of symbol in other project mean going to its source-code?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I go to implementation of a function/class/variable defined in another project I would like IntelliJ to actually go to the relevant source-code of that project. Possibly by linking jar files with projects or raw source-code.
This is possible in Eclipse. Is it also possible in IntelliJ IDEA? Ultimate maybe?

Comment: you can go to implementation by pressing (ctrl + clicking on class/function/variable name),  that will jump you to the actual source code.
This feature available in both commercial and ultimate.

Comment: @NavinGelot Yes, but that doesn't work when the class/function/variable name is in another project. Then it doesn't go to the actual source code (how could it by default when it only has the jar). Instead it jump to skeleton of the definitions inferred from the jar where it at the top says:
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available

Comment: Do you have sources added for external project dependency in "Project Structure | LIbraries"?

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks a lot. That is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Project Structure | Libraries" select a project and add the sources to the project.

At the time of writing there is a list of projects to the left and elements belonging to the selected project on the right (classes/sources). Click the + icon and select the directory of the project.